# How can I show and hide markers on google map in android using a button

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dictionary, marker

I am new to android coding. I am trying to toggle on and off markers that I managed to display on my map, with a button in my action bar.

So far I have created this method, I do not understand what I need to do next

Here, basically I make an array of locations and use for loop to put all the markers on my map. Now what I want to be able to do is hide the markers if they are visible via a button click and show the markers if they are hidden.

```
public boolean showShops(){
        rL = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        rl.add(new LatLng(40.433433, -1.422423));
        rl.add(new LatLng(40.433434, -1.422534));

        for(LatLng nRL : rL){ 
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions() 
            .position(nRL)
            .title("Shop")
        }

        return true;
    }
```

I have been trying to figure it out for a long time now and cannot seem to find the solution. I have managed to find out that you have to setVisible(false); to hide and setVisible(true); to show, but I do not know how I can implement it. I tried adding that instead of .add in my above code but I get errors.

Can someone please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please give me an example, I have been searching regarding this for ages and to date no result. It is getting irritating now. Thanks

Comment: @vitalnik The question you posted is not about Android. Refrain from posting sh** that further irritates the original poster.

Answer (score 2):

If there's nothing else on your map that you DON'T want to hide, use
[clear](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#clear%28%29) on your `GoogleMap` object which removes all additional overlays of your map.

If that method doesn't fit you, you have to keep a reference to all markers (for example in an ArrayList) and call [remove](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker.html#remove%28%29) or [setVisible()](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker.html#setVisible%28boolean%29) on each of them individually:

Keep an

```
ArrayList<Marker> myMarkers = new ArrayList<Marker>();
```

and also add every marker that you add to the map to that list.

```
for(LatLng nRL : rL){ 
  myMarkers.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions() 
        .position(nRL)
        .title("Shop"));
    }
```

If you want to set them all to invisible, iterate over that list and `setVisible(false)` on all of them.

```
 for (Marker m : myMarkers) {
   m.setVisible(false);
 }
```

Comment: I would like to toggle off their visibility, I cannot figure out a way to do that.

Comment: I meant you have to initialize the ArrayList before using it (see edit).
You need to know how to use ArrayLists though to use this solution (no offense).

Comment: Right, you are. You should be able to apply the solution now :)

Comment: Hi, sorry to bother you again, I cannot figure out where to add the latitudes and longitudes on that array list. Also, it tells me to make the LatLng in the for loop to a Marker.The method position(LatLng) in the type MarkerOptions is not applicable for the arguments (Marker)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your marker invisible you can also use `marker.setAlpha(0)`.